# Change position of UIButton when pressed

Tags: objective-c, uibutton

I have a problem with moving at random position an UIButton when pressed. The exercise is to make an app that counts the taps on the button. On each tap the button must change his position on the screen. Here is my code:

```
@implementation ViewController


- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
}


- (IBAction)buttonPressed:(id)sender {

    //[self tapCountMethod];

}

- (IBAction)button:(UIButton *)sender {
    UIButton *button = (UIButton *)sender;

    int xmin = ([button frame].size.width)/2;
    int ymin = ([button frame].size.height)/2;

    int x = xmin + arc4random_uniform(self.view.frame.size.width - button.frame.size.width);
    int y = ymin + arc4random_uniform(self.view.frame.size.height - button.frame.size.height);


    [button setCenter:CGPointMake(x, y)];
    [button addTarget:self action: @selector(buttonPressed:) forControlEvents: UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

}

- (void) tapCounter {

    tapCount ++;
    labelCount.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld times", (long)tapCount];
}


@end
```

So when I call the tapCount method in buttonpressed the button stops moving. Can somebody tell me why this is happening and where I'm wrong. Of you have any suggestions please tell me. Where I must call the count method?

Comment: @property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *button;

- (IBAction)button:(UIButton *)sender {
    int xmin = ([self.button frame].size.width)/2;
    int ymin = ([self.button frame].size.height)/2;
    int x = xmin + arc4random_uniform(self.view.frame.size.width - self.button.frame.size.width);
    int y = ymin + arc4random_uniform(self.view.frame.size.height - self.button.frame.size.height);
    [self.button setCenter:CGPointMake(x, y)];
    [self.button addTarget:self action: @selector(buttonPressed:) forControlEvents: UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
}

This doesn't help me. Still the same

Comment: Not clear how you are wiring this up from interface builder, but you probably shouldn't be adding a target to the button in your "button" method. Why not just do both jobs (move, count) in one method, or at least directly call your move and count methods from the IBAction method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So with many tries and researches I found a solution. Here is my last code.

```
@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {

    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.button.imageView.animationImages =
    [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[UIImage imageNamed:@"image1.png"],
     [UIImage imageNamed:@"image2.png"],
     nil];
    self.button.imageView.animationDuration = 0.7; //whatever you want (in seconds)
    [self.button.imageView startAnimating];
    self.labelCount.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:64./255. green:64./255. blue:64./255. alpha:1.];

}

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {

    [super viewDidAppear:animated];

}


- (IBAction)buttonPressed:(id)sender {
    NSInteger counter = self.tapCount;
    if (counter > 0 )
        [self.labelCount setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld",((long)counter + 1)]]; 
    self.tapCount ++;
    NSLog(@"%ld",(long)self.tapCount);

}

- (IBAction)button:(UIButton *)sender {

    int xmin = ([self.button frame].size.width)/2;
    int ymin = ([self.button frame].size.height)/2;

    int x = xmin + arc4random_uniform(self.view.frame.size.width - self.button.frame.size.width);
    int y = ymin + arc4random_uniform(self.view.frame.size.height - self.button.frame.size.height);


    [self.button setCenter:CGPointMake(x, y)];
    [self.button addTarget:self action: @selector(buttonPressed:) forControlEvents: UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [self.labelCount setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"1"]];
}

- (BOOL)prefersStatusBarHidden {

    return YES;

}

@end
```

Thank you all

Comment: still seems bizarre that you re-add buttonPressed as the action to your button every time it is pressed. and by the way, it looks like your button can't land anywhere in the view frame, because you should be subtracting xmin and ymin rather than the full button height or width.

Comment: I understand you but when I re-add only button as an action to my button the text of the label doesn't change. I tested the app on simulator and device and it works like a charm. The button pass all over the screen.

Comment: What you should do is wire the button to its action *one time*, in interface builder. Perhaps what you want is that every time the button is pressed, you want button: called, and inside the button: method you call the buttonPressed: method to update the label.

Comment: Now I understood you. Thank you very much.